# Trouble with Test Method for SOSL Search

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am having trouble working out how to get my SOSL search page to test with a solid percentage.  The reason I am using SOSL is because of the Long Text Areas that I am searching through.

Here is my Controller:

```
Public with sharing class SOSLController{
Public List<Journal_Entry__c> entList {get;set;}

Public String searchStr{get;set;}
Public SOSLController(){
}

Public void soslDemo_method(){

String userID = UserInfo.getUserId();


entList = New List<Journal_Entry__c>();
if(searchStr.length() > 1){
String searchStr1 = '*'+searchStr+'*';
String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + searchStr1 + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
Journal_Entry__c (Id,Name,DateText__c,Submitted_for_Interp_Count__c,Created_Self_Interp__c,Haven__c,UserID__c 
WHERE UserID__c LIKE :userID)';
List<List <sObject>> searchList = search.query(searchQuery);
entList = ((List<Journal_Entry__c>)searchList[0]);
if(entList.size() == 0){
   apexPages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Error, 'Sory, no results returned with matching string..'));
   return;
}
}
else{
apexPages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Error, 'Please   enter at least two characters..'));
   return;
   }
  }
}
```

And this is what I have so far with my Test...
You will notice that I give the userID string a user Id that works in my VF pages for the test I'm trying to do, but in the Controller, this Id is captured from the active user.

```
@isTest
public class TestSOSLController{ 

public static testMethod void testSoslFixedResults() {

 PageReference myVfPage = Page.MyJournal;
 Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);

 SOSLController testCont = new SOSLController();

 String userID = '00555000001R62HAAS';

   Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
   fixedSearchResults[0] = 'a0955000001ODaU';
   Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
   List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND 'test' 
                                     IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
                                        Journal_Entry__c(Id,Name,DateText__c,Submitted_for_Interp_Count__c,Created_Self_Interp__c,Haven__c,UserID__c 
                                                         WHERE UserID__c     LIKE :userID LIMIT 1)];


        system.assert(searchList != null);
    }
}
```

I understand that SOSL has a special syntax to be used when Testing, based on this page "Adding SOSL Queries to Unit Tests" and you will see that I have attempted to use this, but I am obviously failing misserably.

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a database isolation problem. Here, you're trying to set your search results to a hard-coded ID value, but you haven't specified `SeeAllData=true`, so your code *cannot see that record*, which results in no values coming back in the search results.

Instead, create a new record, and set *that* Id value in the fixed search results:

```
Journal_Entry__c je = new Journal_Entry__c();
insert je;
fixedSearchResults[0] = je.Id;
Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
```

---

I might also add, you have a SOSL injection problem. Don't use dynamic search queries when you don't need to:

```
Public with sharing class SOSLController{
    Public List<Journal_Entry__c> entList {get;set;}

    Public String searchStr{get;set;}
    Public SOSLController(){
    }

    Public void soslDemo_method(){
        if(searchStr.length() < 2)
        {
            apexPages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Error, 'Please   enter at least two characters..'));
        } else {
            String searchStr1 = '*'+searchStr+'*';
            List<List <sObject>> searchList = [FIND :searchStr1 IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
                                               Journal_Entry__c (Id,Name,DateText__c,Submitted_for_Interp_Count__c,Created_Self_Interp__c,Haven__c,UserID__c 
                                                                 WHERE UserID__c LIKE :UserInfo.getUserId())];
            entList = ((List<Journal_Entry__c>)searchList[0]);
            if(entList.size() == 0){
                apexPages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Error, 'Sory, no results returned with matching string..'));
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sfdcfox , your improvements upon the actual controller are really nice... Much cleaner.   I created a new controller with your code, and then made a new Test that incorporated your suggestions, and it works, but only covers 8%.  Could you offer some help to bring the % up?

Comment: @anotherSFguy See cropredy's answer-- it should get you pretty close in coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach to getting test coverage and assertions; @sfdcfox comments are of course, valid.as well

```
@isTest
private static void testSoslController() {

  Journal_Entry__c[] jeList = new List<Journal_Entry__c> {new Journal_Entry__c( set your values),
                                                 new Journal_Entry__c ( set your values)
  };
  insert jeList;   // mock test objects

  SOSLController ctlr = new SOSLController();
  ctrl.searchStr = 'foo';                       
  System.assertEquals('foo',ctlr.searchStr); // tests getter/setter

  Test.setFixedSearchResults(new List<ID>{jeList[0].id});
  ctlr.soslDemoMethod();    // invoke the search logic - with at least 1 guaranteed result
  system.assertEquals(false,ApexPages.hasMessages(),'sb no errors');

  Test.setFixedSearchResults(new List<ID>());
  ctlr.soslDemoMethod();    // invoke the search logic - with at least 1 guaranteed result
  system.assert(ApexPages.getMessages()[0].getSummary().contains('no results returned'),ApexPages.hasMessages() 
                                                                                 ? ApexPages.getMessages()[0].getSummary() 
                                                                                 : 'sb error');

  ctrl.searchStr = 'f'; 
  Test.setFixedSearchResults(new List<ID>{jeList[0].id});
  ctlr.soslDemoMethod();    // invoke the search logic - too short a string
  system.assert(ApexPages.getMessages()[1].getSummary().contains('at least two'),ApexPages.hasMessages() 
                                                                                ? ApexPages.getMessages()[ApexPages.getMessages().size()-1].getSummary() 
                                                                                : 'sb search str error');


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much cropedy, I have some questions regarding your code... I'm still learning the coding aspect of SF.  In creating a new jeList, I would assume that the two fields that I need to set are the Name and the UserID__c that I use to compare to the active User, but what would that look like?  This is being done in SF Communities and when I simply "Preview" the page as the Admin, I don't see the page... I have to log in to the community as the user for real testing purposes... so, how do I get the User Id?

Comment: (1) Just use `UserInfo.getUserId()` - since this is a testmethod with static SOSL results, the actual user isn't important so the running user is fine; (2) as for other fields on Journal_Entry__c - any other required field (if name is auto-number, you don't even/can't set that); (3) note also that I just typed in the code and there could be typos

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your fantastic help! I chose @sfdcfox answer because of the help in cleaning up my actual controller, but I learned so much from both answers.  In the end, I am using a combination of answers found both here and on the Salesforce Developer Forum.

Here is my test, which covers 91% when using @sfdcfox version of my controller.

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=true)
public class TestSOSLController
{ 


public static testMethod void testSoslFixedResults() 
{

    Account acc = [Select Id FROM Account Where Name ='Testing'];

    Contact cont = new Contact();
        cont.FirstName = 'TheTest';
        cont.LastName = 'Tester';
        cont.AccountId = acc.Id;
    insert cont;

    Journal_Profile__c jp = new Journal_Profile__c();
    jp.UserID__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    jp.Contact__c = cont.Id;
    insert jp;

    Journal_Entry__c je = new Journal_Entry__c();
    je.Name = 'Test';
    je.UserID__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    je.Journal_Profile__c = jp.Id;
    // Add all required Field here
    insert je;

    PageReference myVfPage = Page.MyJournal;
    Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);

    Id [] fixedSearchResults = new Id[]{je.Id};
    Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);

        SOSLController testCont = new SOSLController();
        testCont.searchStr='';
        testCont.soslDemo_method();

        testCont.searchStr='Test';
        testCont.soslDemo_method();
        // System.assert( testCont.entList  != null);
}

public static testMethod void testNonResults() 
{

    Account acc = [Select Id FROM Account Where Name='Testing'];

    Contact cont = new Contact();
        cont.FirstName = 'TheTest2';
        cont.LastName = 'Tester2';
        cont.AccountId = acc.Id;
    insert cont;

    Journal_Profile__c jp = new Journal_Profile__c();
    jp.UserID__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    jp.Contact__c = cont.Id;
    insert jp;

    Journal_Entry__c je = new Journal_Entry__c();
    je.Name = 'Test';
    je.UserID__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    je.Journal_Profile__c = jp.Id;
    // Add all required Field here
    insert je;

    PageReference myVfPage = Page.MyJournal;
    Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);

    Id [] fixedSearchResults = new Id[]{je.Id};
    Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);

    SOSLController testCont = new SOSLController();

    testCont.searchStr='Demo';
    testCont.soslDemo_method();
}

}
```

Again, Thank you all very much! I really learned so much in the last 24 hours!